Using the PayPal Show Dispute Details, some responses have a missing reason in adjudications. What's different about these disputes?
When using the PayPal Show Dispute Details API, I have some responses where adjudications are missing a reason. Happens rarely but has been a consistent issue.
My current best guess is that the the chargeback happened externally (through their credit card) and PayPal can't supply a reason.
If anybody can confirm or enlighten me, would greatly appreciate it!
What I'm seeing from my problem dispute.
   "adjudications" : [
      {
         "adjudication_time" : "XXXX-XX-XXTXX:XX:",
         "dispute_life_cycle_stage" : "CHARGEBACK",
         "type" : "PAYOUT_TO_BUYER"
      }
   ],

Expecting something similar to.
   "adjudications" : [
      {
         "adjudication_time" : "XXXX-XX-XXTXX:XX:",
         "dispute_life_cycle_stage" : "CHARGEBACK",
         "reason" : "VALID_PROOF_OF_DELIVERY",
         "type" : "DENY_BUYER"
      }
   ],

Read through documentations. Reason is not required. Reached out on PayPal's forum.

your best guess about it being an external chargeback (at the card level) hence no reason seems accurate to me, not sure anyone other than PayPal will be able to confirm
